# how to use value of variable in java as table name of mysql？

Tags: java, mysql, sql

code:

```
String myTblN = fileN[0];

PreparedStatement creatTableStmt = 
    conn.prepareStatement("create table " + myTblN +" like stocktradtbl");
System.out.println(creatTableStmt);
creatTableStmt.execute();
```

error:

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: create table 00002 like
>   stocktradtbl java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 00002 like
>   stocktradtbl' at line 1

How to use value of variable `myTblN` in java as table name of mysql？

Comment: `00002` is not a valid identifier, since identifiers must start with a letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near **00002 like stocktradtbl**' at line 1

It looks like you are trying to create a table whose name contains only digits. AS explained in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html), MySQL by default does not allow digits at *the beginning* of the table name.

One quick solution would be to add a fixed alphabetic character at the beginning of the table name :

```
PreparedStatement creatTableStmt = 
    conn.prepareStatement("create table t" + myTblN +" like stocktradtbl");
```

Or you need to quote the identifier (but then be prepare to quote the table name in every subsequent query, which can be painful):

```
PreparedStatement creatTableStmt = 
    conn.prepareStatement("create table `" + myTblN +"` like stocktradtbl");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your values need to be quoted with backticks or double-quotes

```
"create table `" + myTblN +"` like `stocktradtbl`"
```

Also as per @kartik

*Also, you may want to add the reason that 00002 consists only of numbers, and mysql allows number-only identifiers only if they are quoted.*

Comment: I think it should be quoted with backticks, not apostrophes

Comment: Also, you may want to add the reason that `00002` consists only of numbers, and mysql allows number-only identifiers only if they are quoted.